# How do I access Object attributes list in python shell while using MS VS code running on Windows 10?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do I access Python attribute list in MS Visual Studio Code shell on Windows 10?

When I type `Object.(dot)` and then tab, the options of what I can do is NOT displayed as shown in the attached picture. I'm running python 3.9.7

[image: pix]

I expected to get a list of attributes of that object/variable (as shown in the above screenshot) when I click on tab but rather, it moves 4 spaces forward.

Comment: the python REPL does not do suggestions, use the IDLE program if you want this behavior in a REPL, or use the interactive Python `#%%` and the debug prompt in the 'Jupyther' viewer

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25606/1624654) on askubuntu.com by [@StefanoPalazzo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1067/stefano-palazzo):

> First, create a new file called `.pythonstartup.py` in your home directory. Put the following script in it:
>
> ```
> try:
>     import readline
> except ImportError:
>     print("Module readline not available.")
> else:
>     import rlcompleter
>     readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
> ```
>
> The parentheses around the string ensure that it works with both Python 2 and Python 3.
>
> Every time the interactive interpreter is started, it executes a script defined in `$PYTHONSTARTUP`, if there is one. To set it to execute the above script, type
>
> ```
> export PYTHONSTARTUP="~/.pythonstartup.py"
> ```
>
> You should write this line to your [`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528/bashrc-or-bash-profile) file, so that it's automatically executed when a new shell is started.

Also related: [How to enable python repl autocomplete and still allow new line tabs](/q/25434997)